# Get all possible pairs out of a list of names

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of names such as :

```
let members = ["John", "Marie", "Ivy", "Daniel"];
```

Each person has to deliver a unique item to another. Here is an example of 1 combination set :

```
[
    {"John":"Marie"},
    {"Marie":"Ivy"},
    {"Ivy":"Daniel"},
    {"Daniel":"John"},
]
```

The reciever can only be named once. I'd like to retrieve an array of all combinations possible. What would be the easiest way to get such an array ?

**EDIT** : Alot of downvotes. Justified I'm afraid. Here is what I worked on, seems... verbose :

```
//gets all permutations combination of the same array    
const perm = members => members.length ? members.reduce((r, v, i) => [ ...r, ...perm([ ...members.slice(0, i), ...members.slice(i + 1) ]).map(x => [ v, ...x ])], []) : [[]]


let permutations = perm(members);

permutations.map(set => {
    let valid = true;
    let combination = [];

    set.map((name, i) => {
        let match = {};
        if (name === members[i]) {
            valid = false;
            return
        }
        match[members[i]] = name;
        combination.push(match);
    })

    if (valid) possibilities.push(combination);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let rslt = []

let members = ["John", "Marie", "Ivy", "Daniel"];

members.forEach((member, i) => { 
    let nextIndex = i + 1;

    // if it's the last member
    // then pass it to the first one
    if (nextIndex === members.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }
    let obj = new Object();
    obj[member] = members[nextIndex];
    rslt.push(obj);
})

console.log(rslt);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It works to give me 1 combination. I'm looking for ALL possible combinations.